# python get count of unique values per key and unique count of value in keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following dictionary:

```
dictA = { 
    'a' : ['duck','duck','goose'], 
    'b' : ['goose','goose'], 
    'c' : ['duck','duck','duck'], 
    'd' : ['goose'], 
    'e' : ['duck','goose'] 
    }
```

I want to get the following results:

```
{
    'duck': {'countALL':3, 'countDoc': {'a': 2, 'b': 0, 'c': 3, 'd': 0, 'e':1}},
    'goose': {'countALL':4, 'countDoc': {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 0, 'd': 1, 'e':1}},
}
```

Comment: did you try anything worth posting?

Comment: Your expected results aren't a valid object. you have a keyless entry in a dict. (or a keyed entry in a set)

Comment: @ChrisCharles I fixed the error, please see the updated question

Comment: unclear, why `duck` has `'countALL':3` ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Because it appears in 3 separate lists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
unique_items = set(x for y in dictA.values() for x in y)

new_dict = {}
for item in unique_items:
    new_dict[item] = {'countALL': sum(1 for x in dictA if item in dictA[x]), 'countDoc': {k: v.count(item) for k, v in dictA.items()}}
print(new_dict)
# {'goose': {'countALL': 4, 'countDoc': {'e': 1, 'a': 1, 'c': 0, 'b': 2, 'd': 1}}, 'duck': {'countALL': 3, 'countDoc': {'e': 1, 'a': 2, 'c': 3, 'b': 0, 'd': 0}}}
```

Note that the order on the inner dict is *random*.

There are two interesting points to this:

- the generator expression that counts the lists that contain `item`: `sum(1 for x in dictA if item in dictA[x])`.
- and the dict comprehension that gets the count in each list: `{k: v.count(item) for k, v in dictA.items()}`

But they are both relatively easy to read so I will leave that to you for now. If you have any questions feel free to ask though.

Answer (score 2):

If the lists are very large, it might pay off to create [`collection.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) instances first, instead of repeatedly calling `list.count`:

```
>>> words = set(word for lst in dictA.values() for word in lst)
>>> counts = {k: Counter(v) for k, v in dictA.items()}
>>> counts
{'a': Counter({'duck': 2, 'goose': 1}), 'd': Counter({'goose': 1}), 
 'b': Counter({'goose': 2}), 'c': Counter({'duck': 3}), 
 'e': Counter({'goose': 1, 'duck': 1})}
```

The result can then be assembles using a "simple" nested dictionary-comprehension:

```
>>> {word: {"countALL": sum(word in c for c in counts.values()), 
...         "countDoc": {k: v.get(word, 0) for k, v in counts.items()}}
...  for word in words}
{'duck':  {'countALL': 3, 'countDoc': {'a': 2, 'd': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 3, 'e': 1}},
 'goose': {'countALL': 4, 'countDoc': {'a': 1, 'd': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 0, 'e': 1}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dictA = { 
    'a' : ['duck','duck','goose'], 
    'b' : ['goose','goose'], 
    'c' : ['duck','duck','duck'], 
    'd' : ['goose'], 
    'e' : ['duck','goose'] 
    }

dictB = {}
mySetOfKeys=set()

for myKey in dictA:
    mySetOfKeys.add(myKey)
    for myBird in dictA[myKey]:
        if dictB.has_key(myBird):
            if dictB[myBird]['countDoc'].has_key(myKey):
                dictB[myBird]['countDoc'][myKey] += 1
            else:
                dictB[myBird]['countALL'] += 1
                dictB[myBird]['countDoc'][myKey] = 1
        else:
            dictB[myBird] = {'countALL':1,'countDoc':{myKey:1}}

for myBird in dictB:
    for myKey in mySetOfKeys:
        if dictB[myBird]['countDoc'].has_key(myKey):
            pass
        else:
            dictB[myBird]['countDoc'][myKey] = 0
print dictB
print mySetOfKeys

    enter code here
```